# Command-t plugin for Vim ignoring folders directly inside the user folder

Tags: macos, vim, plugins, macvim

I have just installed Command-t on MacVim, OS X Lion. It works but for some reason it won't list any folder on the user folder except for the OS X Lion's defaults. I have already tried :CommandTFlush, restarting MacVim and reinstalling the plugin.